# How to load two states in a React native FlatList, is it possible?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have two states below.

```
state={
   title=['abc','def','ghi'];    //data for-example.
   Subheading=['aaa','bbb','ccc']; //data for-example.
}
```

And i want following output via FlatList.

```
abc
aaa

def
bbb

ghi
ccc
```

Code I have tried can load title state only but how to load subheading along with title in a Text component.

My code is similar:

```
 <FlatList
       style={{ flex: 1, padding: 9 }}
       data={Object.assign(this.state.title)}
       keyExtractor={(key, index) => key + index}
       renderItem={(itemData) => {

         return <Card.Title
                 title={itemData.item}
                 subtitle={<Text>//how to load subheading</Text>}
                 onPress={() => console.log("Pressed")}>
                 />
             }
           }
   />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the `index` of the rendered item in `renderItem`, and since you have a 1:1 equivalence between the indices of `title` and `subheading` you can use that to access the data you need:

```
 <FlatList
       style={{ flex: 1, padding: 9 }}
       data={Object.assign(this.state.title)}
       keyExtractor={(key, index) => key + index}
       renderItem={(itemData) => {

         return <Card.Title
                 title={itemData.item.name}
                 subtitle={<Text>{this.state.Subheading[itemData.index]}</Text>}  /* <- Here */
                 onPress={() => console.log("Pressed")}>
                 />
             }
           }
   />
```

Also, you should remove the `Object.assign()` in the `data` prop and just pass the title in since it's not doing anything.

Answer (score 1):

There are few ways to do this but I think the cleaner way is to merge the arrays in to a object of this form `[{ title: 'aaa', subtitle: 'abc' }]`

```
const data = title.map( (item,index) => {
       return { title: item, subtitle: Subheading[index] }
}
```

Then in your flatlist you can use `item.title` and `item.subtitle`

From a programmer point of view, I will always organise my data in a structured and readable way so that eventually, my rendering codes will also be readable (instead of multiple arrays[index])

Answer (score 0):

I could think of 2 ways for this

1. You could merge your two arrays into and array of objects (This requires data structure change)
2. `renderItem({ item, index, separators });` the signature of the function has index in it, if you are 100% sure that title at index 0 has subbheading at index 0, you could simply write `this.state.subheading[index]` to get the subheading value